# Circular dependency on injection within same class library

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I have below classes and implementation inside same class library

```
public interface IA
    {

    }

    public class A : IA
    {
        private IB _ib;

        public A(IB ib)
        {
            _ib = ib;
        }
    }

    public interface IB
    {

    }

    public class B : IB
    {
        private IA _ia;

        public B(IA ia)
        {
            ia = _ia;
        }
    }
```

My question is when, either IA or IB, gets instantiated, will it create any circular dependency when performing dependency injection? If so, how can this be resolved?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: One option to consider would be to use `Lazy`. Another option is to **not** have A dependent on B and vice versa. Instead add C, which has IA and IB as dependencies. And each method on A has a IB parameter (and vice versa). Then, call the D method on C which calls the D method on A, passing in the B as the parameter.

Comment: yeah... you would have a runtime issue. resolution depends on what you are really trying to do. general solution is to have a third class in play

Comment: You don't need dependency injection here to realise that there's a problem - just try `new`ing up an `A` or a `B` yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will have circular dependency and will throw exception at runtime. You need to refactor your code so that `A` and `B` do not have dependencies on each other. You will need to extract a new interface (`IC`) out of either A or B and refactor your code to something like the following:

```
public interface IA {
}
public class A : IA {
  IC _c;
  public A(IC c) {
    _c = c;
  }
}

public interface IB {
}
public class B : IB {
  IA _a;
  IC _c;
  public B(IA a, IC c) {
    _a = a;
    _c = c;
  }
}

public interface IC {
}
public class C : IC {
}
```

See [Circular Dependency in constructors and Dependency Injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/) on how to refactor your classes to remove circular references

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that yes, it will be an issue.

There are solutions for it, and these solutions depend on what DI container/solution is being used.

Even if you solve the issue, it a strong signal that your design is not ideal and should be revised.

In most cases you should be able easily extract a third interface which A and B depend on.